cosine similarity for text embedding
I tested various text-embedding models, namely:

sentence-transformers/all-MiniLM-L6-v2 (dim: 384)
mixedbread-ai/mxbai-embed-large-v1 (dim: 1024)
intfloat/multilingual-e5-small (dim: 384)

I found that for model2 and model3, which with I get all the result for cosine similarity all above 0.9, even the meaning is totally different.
for example, this is the list of text i test:
list = [
  "reset password",
  "update profile",
  "billing and transaction",
  "terms of service",
  "Privacy policy",
  "ESG policy",
  "the weather is bright today",
  "this is going to be a legal issue",
  "my cat is sick"
]

if I run this query, "I want to change password" with model3 I will get the result below:
#model3
[
         %{["reset password", 0.9828062653541565]},
         %{["terms of service", 0.9620927572250366]},
         %{["billing and transaction", 0.9593185186386108]},
         %{["ESG policy", 0.9535043835639954]},
         %{["update profile", 0.9522604942321777]},
         %{["Privacy policy", 0.9497181177139282]},
         %{["the weather is bright today", 0.9462209939956665]},
         %{["this is going to be a legal issue", 0.9461315274238586]},
         %{["my cat is sick", 0.9426164627075195]}
       ]

as you can see, over all I will get back around 0.9 and above. is this normal? or I missed out something during the process.
I am using neo4j, which is graph database with datascience module to perform the cosine-similarity search.
